# How to customize UILabel clickable

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel

#### What I want:

In an iPhone app, I'd like to show information in a tableView.
In each cell, the text is like: John recently listen to music abcdefg.mp3.
and if needed, the text can have two lines.

In the text,  a.mp3 should be clickable so when the user touches the *abcdefg.mp3* part, another page will be invoked. When user touches *abcdefg.mp3*, it will also have some effects, just like touching a button.

#### What I do:

I calculate the frame of the text, and I use a UIButton for *abcdefg.mp3*.

#### My Problem:

Sometimes *abcdefg.mp3* may be in multiline, like:

> *abc* is at the end of the first line
>
> *defg.mp3* is in second line.

What should I do in this case?

I've already searched about: [Create tap-able "links" in the NSAttributedString of a UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/clickable-links-in-uilabel)
However I think it is not suitable here as the clickable text is all in one line in the sample.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The most simple way is to just add a gesture recognizer to the actual view (be it a UILabel or some custom view of your own). In order for the gesture recognizer to work, the view must be set userInteractionEnabled.

Here's an example, assuming that your label view (or whatever it is) is called labelView:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userTappedOnLink:)];
// if labelView is not set userInteractionEnabled, you must do so
[labelView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[labelView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

In this example, an action message will be sent to `self` and the message would be defined as

`- (void)userTappedOnLink:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer;`

This works the same as wiring up any other UIControl subclass, such as a button.

**Other notes:** don't try to add the same gesture recognizer to multiple views, it won't work. Don't add more than one copy of the gesture recognizer to multiple views (it doesn't replace them, it just stacks them up and wastes memory). You should add the gesture recognizer when you initially create and configure your view.

For more information, see the documentation for [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer).

Comment: thanks~however, I think it is complicated if the clickable area is in two lines.

Comment: @scorpiozj: Nope, not as long as it's all part of the same view.

Comment: @Jason:I also want there will be some effect when user touches the clickable part. if there is line-break in the clickable part, it is not easy to handle it, is it? Or can you explain a little more?
thanks.

Comment: @scorpiozj: I guess I don't fully understand what you mean by 'line-break'. When you have a line-break, do you write the second line in a totally separate view? Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: @Jason: your solution is easy to some extent. But I met another one:
I separate the text"John recently listen to music abcdefg.mp3" into two:"John recently listen to music" and  "abcdefg.mp3". if "abcdefg.mp3" must be shown in two-line, how can I use one control to hold it so that it can add a gestureRecognizer?

Comment: @jason: OK~
it just like below:
John recently listen to music i-like
-sun.mp3

so it is not in a whole line, and the text "i-like-sun.mp3" should be clickable.

Comment: @scorpiozj: Well, if you need that functionality and you're laying out these views yourself, simply add another UIGestureRecognizer instance to your second-line view that has the same target. So, if the user hits either bit, she will create the same action message.

Comment: What about when the gesture recognizer is in a custom label within a tableview cell? In my case this breaks tableview scrolling. I have tried tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false but it doesn't fix tableview scrolling. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

Swift 4.2 Version:

```
var labelView = UILabel()
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(userTappedOnLink))
// if labelView is not set userInteractionEnabled, you must do so
labelView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
labelView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)


@objc func userTappedOnLink() {
    print("clicked!")
}
```

Comment: This is not valid Swift code, looks like you forgot some bits in your attempt to convert the above Objective C code.

Comment: In Swift 3, `userInteractionEnabled` has been renamed `isUserInteractionEnabled `.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.0 version:

```
  func userTappedOnLink() {
    print("clicked!")
  }

///tap and link to FB page
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "userTappedOnLink")
// if labelView is not set userInteractionEnabled, you must do so
lblStaff.userInteractionEnabled = true
lblStaff.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds similar to what they accomplished in Twitteriffic with [Fancy UILabels](http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/). Basically, Craig Hockenberry made his own custom "data detector", so that he could insert links within labels and multi-line text. See this question: [Is there a way to create custom UIDataDetectorTypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358343/is-there-a-way-to-create-custom-uidatadetectortypes)

Comment: I tried FancyLabel, but I think it failed when the clickable part is in multiline. thanks all the same

Answer (score 1):

You could also just put an "invisible Button" above, by using a custom button without text and images.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use textView and diable the scrolling. I did same for my project where I need to point to website addresses.  just uncheck everything as shown in screenshot in 'scroll view' section in inspector window. 
[image: disable scrolling]

Answer (score 0):

By adding `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the label, to make `UIlabel` clickable.

Before adding the label to tapgesture, don't forgot to enable userinteraction for UIlabel

Here is the sample code:

```
//Tap Gesture
UITapGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userTapped:)];
//Adding userinteraction for label
[labelName setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
//Adding label to tap gesture
[labelName addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution for clickable UILabel. It isn't for select link in text. Just nice solution in my opinion for clickable UILabel like UIButton:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ClickableLablelDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)onClickLabel:(UILabel *) label;

@end

@interface ClickableLable : UILabel

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ClickableLablelDelegate> delegate;

@end


#import "ClickableLable.h"

@implementation ClickableLable

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onClickLabel:)]) {
        [_delegate onClickLabel:self];
    }
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Comment: Please explain this