# IOS xcode 6 - Segues don't work

Tags: ios, audio

Hey guys  I am new to iOS coding and am trying to design an alarm clock with multiple view controllers. For that I'm trying to link view controllers with buttons and it works very well but whenever i add a label and linked that label with code the segues don't work
i searched on the net for solution but no luck a little help here will be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do ? Click on the link and transfer to another view or pass the label to the next view ?

Comment: I am trying to click on link and transfer to another view i want to keep the label on the main view itself on the sub-view i used date picker to set the time

Comment: I think this is just what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743457/how-to-customize-uilabel-clickable

Comment: Well thanks but its bit complicated to understand so here are the screenshots i guess looking at them you will know what i am looking for:- preview 1 - http://i61.tinypic.com/33v2m28.jpg : in this as you can see there is working clock now using that button i want to navigate at next view. Preview 2 - http://i60.tinypic.com/2uyioti.jpg : in this i connected button to next view using segue but as you can see the segue don't work when i try to click. But when i remove the clock along with its code then segues work. I don't want to transfer data just move to next view

Comment: i tried connecting view controllers programatically instead of using the built in segues but that also don't work.