# The label in Xcode can clickable to another page?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

What I want to do is click the label and it will lead to another page. Now I am making iOS application using Xcode. I found the information about this in internet but couldn't find related information.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? We shouldn't have to write your code for you.

Comment: Use `UIButton`...

Comment: Tj3n, thank you, I follow ur answer can already

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: how to make a UILabel clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658521/swift-how-to-make-a-uilabel-clickable)

Comment: check the answer on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743457/how-to-customize-uilabel-clickable

Answer (score 3):

You can add a tap gesture like this:

```
 let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapOnLabel(gesure:)))
 YOUR_Label.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

 func didTapOnLabel(gesure:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    //handle your action here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer)  on your label and trigger the action on tap.